# Fabric and Jenkins on CentOS 6.4 /bin/bash can't find binaries

Tags: python, jenkins, continuous-integration, fabric

I have a jenkins installation at work that's hosted on CentOS 6.  I've created a job that executes a shell command as

```
$ fab deploy
```

The fabric script connects to a remote CentOS host and runs a number of binaries, such as:

```
/usr/local/bin/python2.7 setup.py develop
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
/bin/bash: /usr/local/bin/python2.7: No such file or directory
```

The strange thing is that the script when run from my local machine (Mac OS X) has no problems at all.

I connect to the remote CentOS server as root with the following:

```
env.user = 'root'
env.hosts = [REMOTE_HOST]
```

After a little research, I tried

```
env.bash = '/bin/sh -c'
```

But still the same error.  I also tried wrapping the command in run() with bash as

```
run("/bin/bash -l -c '/usr/local/bin/python2.7 setup.py develop'")
```

But I still get the same error when the jenkins job runs.  The python binary is there!  And the fab deploy command works from local, just not on jenkins.

Comment: *"The python binary is there!"* - how exactly did you verify that (on the remote CentOS host)?

Comment: @LukasGraf well, I have ssh access to the host, plus I built python2.7 on it my self, plus the fabric script runs without errors from my local machine

Comment: That still doesn't answer my question. Did you do `ls /usr/local/bin/python2.7` on the remote host? Or type the path and try to start the Python interpreter? Or ...?

Comment: @LukasGraf of course I did!  And if it wasn't there, how would script work from my local machine?

Comment: I'm giving up. I wanted to know **which one** you did. The exact command you entered, and what result you got.

Comment: @LukasGraf OK.  here you go: [root@aws-it-webproxy-prod-01 ~]# ls -al /usr/local/bin/python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6214493 Mar 18 19:27 /usr/local/bin/python2.7

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a VPN access problem.  My local machine wasn't getting past the proxy box, so when I setup python2.7 I actually set it up on the proxy box, and not the box that jenkins was hitting.  Once that was resolved, everything else worked.